# Nginx Ingress Routing rule with Nginx Webserver

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I'm new to Ingress in Kubernetes and ran into the following problem:
When the 'path' in my Ingress is simply "/", then everything works, however, when I change to to something like "/fe" then it breaks, even if I update my target pod's configuration.

Here is a full example of the problem:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: tpi-temp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  namespace: tpi-temp
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-conf
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          subPath: nginx.conf
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-conf
      configMap:
        name: nginx-config
        items:
          - key: nginx.conf
            path: nginx.conf
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: tpi-temp
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  auto;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

        # CORS configuration
        map $http_origin $cors_header {
            default "";
            ~^https?://([^:/?]+)(?::\d+)?$ "$http_origin";
        }

        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name example.com;

            location /fe {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html;

                # Add CORS headers
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $cors_header always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;

                if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                    return 204;
                }
            }

            # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tpi-ingress
  namespace: tpi-temp
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.domain.stackoverflow
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /fe
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

However if I update the path in the ingress definition from "path: /fe" to "path: /" and the location in the nginx configuration from "location /fe" to "location /", then I can access Nginx on my domain.

Details:
K8s distrobution: Microk8s
Ingress controller: Nginx Ingress Controller

Thank you!

Comment: The provided example results in a 404 error.